# Is there any open api for IndianRailway

Tags: web-services

I am working on an app based on railway which requires to get the info of a train or of that railway station.I want an open API for that app which gives the results of PNR status, Live Station, etc..

Can anyone suggest one good API for that?

Comment: try https://rapidapi.com/IRCTCAPI/api/irctc1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked http://api.erail.in/ ?

```
Sample call : http://api.erail.in/stations/?key=API_KEY
```

Json output

```
{
    "status" : "OK",
    "result" : [
                    { 
                        "code" : "NDLS",
                        "name" : "New Delhi"
                    },
                    { 
                        "code" : "BCT",
                        "name" : "Mumbai Central"
                    },
                    ....
                ]
}
```

How to Get eRail API
First and foremost, app developers will need to get an API key which    Allows you to monitor your application’s API usage in the API console

- Enables per-key instead of per-IP-address quota limits.
- Ensures that eRail.in can contact you about your application if necessary.

The eRail.in Indian Railways API uses an API key to identify your application. API keys are managed through the eRail.in APIs console. To create your key:

1. Please send a request to info@erail.in
2. Upon approval you will be provided with the API key
3. Once the service has been activated, you can make HTTP request to the API.

Answer (score 0):

The eRail.in Indian Railways API uses an API key to identify your application. API keys are managed through the eRail.in APIs console.

To create your key:

1. Please send a request to info@erail.in
2. Upon approval you will beprovided with the API key
3. Once the service has been activated, you can make HTTP request to
   the API.

For more details, you can refer https://indianrailapi.com/api-collection